# Set width for the pinned columns group

Tags: ag-grid

Is it possible to set a certain width for my pinned columns section. In my application the use will have up to freeze columns and 20 unpinned columns. It gets tedious to scroll to the unpinned columns every time. Instead I want a scroll for my pinned columns with the section defined to certain width.

Comment: share what you have done so far for this via plunk, stackblitz. Go through how to create [mcve]